# Store text in a txt file in python

Tags: python

Okay so I am making a program to test if certain pages in a website are offline or online.

```
import urllib2

u = 'http://www.google.com/'

pages =  open('pages.txt', 'r').readlines()

for page in pages:
    url = u + page
    try:
        req = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
        if e.code == 404:
            print url + " does not exists"
    else:
        print url + " exists"
```

and the "Pages.txt" contains something like this:

```
search
page
plus
signin
account
security
lol
about
contactus
someotherpage.html
```

Now the program is working fine but I want it to store the available pages in a txt file. Can someone help me with that? If not just listing the pages that exist and forgetting the offline pages would be also great. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

What about :

python your_script > Pages.txt

---

**Edit**

For writing in a file

```
with open('Pages.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('something')
f.close()
```

Comment: won't that just store everything? I don't want the offline sites to appear

Comment: But my print also contains the "doesn't exist" pages

Comment: but I have a question, why did someone give me a dislike? Is my question wrong?

Comment: Because you basically waiting for us to write code for you :) Here how to write good question : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hmm, maybe because I am still a beginner? And look at the other answers a dude actually wrote the code for me but I am asking him why he used it and so. I am willing to learn and if I don't won't to write my codes I won't write the above one in the first place :)

Comment: You right, but if you manage to write this code, I pretty sure you will be good to find the way how to write in a file and I actually give you a pointer... Also here the Input/Output Python documentation : https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: Oh okay I will check it out :) And thanks for improving my question :)

Comment: No prob!! You can accept an answer or at least up vote the one that help you... That the way we are rewarded.

Comment: Well they say I need reputation to vote? Can you please tell me how to get reputation?

Comment: Answer others questions, edit question and answer and get accepted edit, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just write to the file in the same way you're reading:

`out =  open('pages.txt', 'w')`

... then in the `else:` tag you've already written:

`out.write(url+"\n")`

Making:

`import urllib2`

`u = 'http://www.google.com/'
pages =  open('pages.txt', 'r').readlines()
out =  open('pages.txt', 'w')
for page in pages:
    url = u+page
    try:
            req = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
            if e.code == 404:
                    print url+" does not exists"
    else:
            print url+" exists"
            out.write(url+"\n")`

Comment: Well I am still new to python, can you please write the final code? Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Open up a file in append mode to write to.
Redirect the print statement to print to the new file handler.

```
import urllib2

u = raw_input('Enter a url: ') or 'http://www.google.com/'

pages =  open('pages.txt', 'r').readlines()
with open('available.txt', 'a') as available:
    for page in pages:
        url = u.rstrip('\n')+page
        try:
                req = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
                if e.code == 404:
                        print url+" does not exists"
        else:
                print url+" exists"
                print >> available, url.rstrip('\n')
```

Output:

```
(availablepages)macbook:availablepages joeyoung$ ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 joeyoung  staff  136 Sep  7 00:23 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 joeyoung  staff  136 Sep  6 23:54 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 joeyoung  staff  478 Sep  7 00:20 availablepages.py
-rw-r--r--  1 joeyoung  staff   70 Sep  6 23:56 pages.txt
(availablepages)macbook:availablepages joeyoung$ python availablepages.py 
Enter a url: http://www.google.com/
http://www.google.com/search
 exists
http://www.google.com/page
 does not exists
http://www.google.com/plus
 exists
http://www.google.com/signin
 does not exists
http://www.google.com/account
 exists
http://www.google.com/security
 exists
http://www.google.com/lol
 does not exists
http://www.google.com/about
 exists
http://www.google.com/someotherpage.html
 does not exists
(availablepages)macbook:availablepages joeyoung$ ls -al
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  5 joeyoung  staff  170 Sep  7 00:23 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 joeyoung  staff  136 Sep  6 23:54 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 joeyoung  staff  145 Sep  7 00:23 available.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 joeyoung  staff  478 Sep  7 00:20 availablepages.py
-rw-r--r--  1 joeyoung  staff   70 Sep  6 23:56 pages.txt
(availablepages)macbook:availablepages joeyoung$ cat available.txt 
http://www.google.com/search
http://www.google.com/plus
http://www.google.com/account
http://www.google.com/security
http://www.google.com/about
(availablepages)macbook:availablepages joeyoung$ python availablepages.py 
Enter a url: http://www.bing.com/
http://www.bing.com/search
 exists
http://www.bing.com/page
 does not exists
http://www.bing.com/plus
 does not exists
http://www.bing.com/signin
 does not exists
http://www.bing.com/account
 exists
http://www.bing.com/security
 does not exists
http://www.bing.com/lol
 does not exists
http://www.bing.com/about
 does not exists
http://www.bing.com/someotherpage.html
 does not exists
(availablepages)macbook:availablepages joeyoung$ ls -al
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  5 joeyoung  staff  170 Sep  7 00:23 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 joeyoung  staff  136 Sep  6 23:54 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 joeyoung  staff  200 Sep  7 00:24 available.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 joeyoung  staff  478 Sep  7 00:20 availablepages.py
-rw-r--r--  1 joeyoung  staff   70 Sep  6 23:56 pages.txt
(availablepages)macbook:availablepages joeyoung$ cat available.txt 
http://www.google.com/search
http://www.google.com/plus
http://www.google.com/account
http://www.google.com/security
http://www.google.com/about
http://www.bing.com/search
http://www.bing.com/account
```

Comment: Thanks a lot really! just one thing maybe this is a silly question but what is the available.txt? Is it generated automatically or should I create it? Thanks again :)

Comment: Sorry, it's generated automatically.  You can change the filename to anything you want in the code.

Comment: Okay it worked perfectly! Thanks a lot :) I know I should probably ask this in a separate question but Can I make the user choose the site? Your answer has been marked as useful :)

Comment: Yes. See the edit.  Although, do note that with the way you create your full URL, the script will error if the user doesn't enter the trailing slash for the site he wishes to execute this against.